Closed-form expression for the projection into subspaces of a hyperbolic space
Good morning,
I've been busy with the following problem:
Given a model $\mathbb{H}^n$ for the hyperbolic space of constant sectional curvature -1 and a hyperbolic subspace $V=\exp_p(A)$, where $A$ is a subspace for $T_p\mathbb{H}^n$ and $\exp$ is the Riemannian exponential, and $w\in\mathbb{H}^n.$
Is there a closed-form expression for the orthogonal/metric projection $\pi_{V}$ into $V$, either providing $\pi_V(w)$ or $\exp_p^{-1}\pi_V(w)$?
Further, is there a formula for dist$(w,V)$?
This has already been considered for dim$A=1$ in a previous post.
However, I was not able to find a generalization. In particular, I tried simplifying the situation to $p= (0,...,0,-1), V=\mathbb{R}^k$ using the frame-homogeneity of $\mathbb{H}^n$.
Further, [Bridson, Haeflinger], II.2.4, yields the existence and uniqueness of such projections.
Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance.
